# Run tests in single Spec in parallel ini kotest

Tags: kotest

I wanted to run kotest in the same spec in parallel. I read the below section in the documentation. But it says you can run only specs in parallel, tests in the single spec will always run sequentially.

https://kotest.io/docs/framework/project-config.html#parallelism

Is there a way to achieve parallelism at the test level? I'm using kotest for my e2e API testing. All tests are independent and should have no problem running them in parallel. But with kotest, I can't. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable concurrent tests on a per-spec basis or a global basis.

For example:

```
class MySpec : FunSpec({
  concurrency = 10
   test("1") { }
   test("2") { }
}
```